# PHP - passing arguments to my DB query methods using PDO

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and OOP, I am building methods in order to gather articles from an articles database, my method will receive three parameters: $limit, $category, $order. I think this are self explanatory, however I have a few issues.

-What happens if one of the arguments is missing, will the method return false? how can I avoid this?

-I don't know how to gather attributes from two related tables, that is each article belongs to a category.

-Should I put each of the methods I am building inside a try cath clause, will this be benefitial for me or an my if-elses will do the trick?

-Am I doing parameter binding right? or should I specify the thir argument which I think is the type I should be expecting the variable to be, but what if the var introduced is different form the expected type?

Here are my related tables, I think I set up their relationship correctly.

Categories table

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
  id                     SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- Each article unique identifier:
  categoryId             SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,                 -- The artcle category id:
  image                  VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'images/img_default_article.jpg',                      -- Main image of the article:
  title                  TEXT NOT NULL,                              -- Full title of the article:
  summary                TEXT NOT NULL,                              -- The summary of the article:
  content                MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,                        -- The HTML content of the article:
  created                DATE NOT NULL,                              -- Day and Month the article entry was created
  modified               TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, --Timestamp the article was last edited
  visible                INT(11) NOT NULL,                           -- 1 - Visible, 0 - Not visible:


  PRIMARY KEY     (id)
  FOREIGN KEY     (categoryId) REFERENCES categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)

ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='all the articles available';
```

Articles table

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id              SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,         -- Category unique identifier
  image           TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "images/img_default_category.jpg",    -- Image of the article
  name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,                             -- Name of the category:
  description     TEXT NOT NULL,                                     -- A short description of the category:

  PRIMARY KEY     (id)
)

ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT="Categories for all th articles";
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
class Article extends BaseEntity{
    private $id, $categoryid, $author, $image, $title, $summary, $content, $created, $modified, $visible;

    public function __construct($adapter) {
        $table="articles";
        parent::__construct($table, $adapter);
    }



    public function getArticlesAdv($limit, $category, $order){
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM articles
                ORDER BY created DESC";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->execute()){

            $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();
            if(numrows>0){

                while ($row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                {
                $resultSet[]=$row;
                }
                return $resultSet;

            }
            else
            {   
            return false;
            }   
        }

        else
        {
        return false;   
        }
    }

    public function getAllArticles(){
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM articles
                ORDER BY created DESC";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $numrows = $stmt->rowCount();

        if(numrows>0){

        while ($row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
           $resultSet[]=$row;
        }

        return $resultSet;

        }
        else{
            return false;
        }


    }

?>
```

Comment: This is kind of like *lots* of questions all rolled into one basically asking if you're doing it right (rather than trying to fix one broken thing)... this might actually be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answers I-III** : Depending on your `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` being set to  `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, you might need to put try catch or simply check `PDO::errorCode()` [see more on pdo error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and as for the result for missing any parameters `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` will decide what you receive for it whether it is an exception or a null set or null.

**Answer II** : To gather data from 2 or more tables, you can use [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). an example for you tables might be :

```
SELECT `a`.`title`, `c`.`name` AS `category_name` FROM `articles` AS `a` INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON (`a`.`categoryId` = `c`.`id`);
```

> `c`.`name` AS `category_name`

this is called aliasing, whether it is on a column or a table, once you `alias` it, you can use the alias in anywhere of your query instead of the actual name.

> INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON (`a`.`categoryId` = `c`.`id`)

this means to get the corresponding data from the table `categories` which is aliased as `c` where the `categoryId` column from `articles` table is equal to `id` column from `categories` table.

**Answer IV** : Depending on whether you have set the **strict mode** enabled for your mysql server, not using the third parameter (which defaults to `PDO::PARAM_STR`) on an int column, will result with error. 
Even if you don't have the strict mode set, but you sent wrong type of variable type declaration, such as sending `'1'` (`PDO::PARAM_STR`) on an int column instead of `1` (`PDO::PARAM_INT`) and if you have an index on that column, your query will not use index, resulting in poor performance.

I was not able to see any binding in your code, but remember there are 3 types of binding available in PDO which are [bindColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php), [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

I'll place an example with `bindValue` as the difference between them or sll types of usage styles are out of this context.

```
public function getArticlesAdv($limit, $category, $order){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE `categoryId` = :category ORDER BY ";
    switch($order) {
       case 'categoryId':
           $sql .="categoryId";
           break;
       case 'visible':
           $sql .="categoryId";
           break;
       default:
           $sql .="id";
           break;
    }
    $sql .= ' DESC LIMIT 0,:limit';

    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue($category,':category',PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue($limit,':limit',PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($resultSet) return $resultSet;
        return array();
     catch(Exception $ex) {
        return array();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I'd suggest you some docs:

PHP OOP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

PHP PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

At the moment you are not using ($limit, $category, $order).
In order to make them optional you have to set a default value into the declaration of the function:

```
public function getArticlesAdv($limit = 10, $category = null, $order = 'articles.id'){
```

order itself is not enough (order by ... ASC/DESC) so I'd modify your function with:

```
public function getArticlesAdv($limit = 10, $category = null, $order = 'articles.id', $orderType = 'asc'){
```

once you modify it you need to create the proper SQL statement:

```
 $where = "";
 if($category){
    $where = " where categoryID = $category ";
  }

  $sql = "SELECT a.*,c*
          FROM articles a join categories c on a.categoryID = c.id 
          $where              
          ORDER BY $order $orderType $limit";
```

I've put **a.*,c.*** because otherwise you'll get an ambiguity error (same for the limit)

This is just ONE of many ways to do it.

Hope it will help.